# How to get status of oracle weblogic

Tags: weblogic11g

I have a weblogic 11g and i wanto to create an program to check status of weblogic. I want to know how to check the status. Is the weblogic write status in a file?. If weblogic write the status in a file, i can using program if the status of file write changed, the program must send an email to me.

Is it possible?

Comment: you can use WLST scripts to check  health server

Comment: @devwebcl can you help me how to create WLST script and how to call it from java

Answer (score 0):

If the idea is to use Java then it is better to use JMX directly (WLST is more used as command line solution).

There is an example in Oracle documentation that may help you:

Print the Name and State of Servers
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13728/accesswls.htm#JMXCU156

Comment: i have tried this link : http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/e13728/accesswls.htm#JMXCU158 , and i tried to follow the code, and i change array of args like this:        
String hostname = "::1";
String portString = "7101";
String username = "weblogic";
String password = "W3bL061c*#";

Comment: but, i get an error like :
java.net.MalformedURLException: Unsupported protocol: t3
at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.newJMXConnector(JMXConnectorFactory.java:359)
at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:269)
at MonitoringMain.initConnection(MonitoringMain.java:115)
at MonitoringMain.main(MonitoringMain.java:29) .

Comment: how to fix it? i think the java doesn't understand t3, if i change into ipv4, the java get an error too.

Comment: add wlfullclient.jar to your classpath, this file can be generated from your WLS installation:
http://docs.oracle.com/html/E13717_06/jarbuilder.htm